# How to increase the amplitude of a colpitts oscillator circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, oscillator

[image: oscillator circuit]

This oscillator works at 1.1 MHz frequency and its amplitude is 0.4 volt but I want to increase it to between 4 to 6 volts.

Comment: Add an amplifier.

Comment: Are you sure it oscillates at 1.1 MHz? Looks more like something around 10kHz with those component values.

Comment: yes i'm sure it is 1.1 Mhz ,i test it

Comment: Where are you measuring the amplitude?

Comment: i measured it in laboratory with oscilloscope

Comment: Smells to me like you have some parasitic oscillation. I suggest to enter this circuit in a simulator and then see if it's still oscillating at 1 MHz. For more amplitude: I agree, use an amplifier.

Comment: Where? Brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C127 is way way too big  reduce it and your output will increase .In fact its normally smaller than C129 because a common base transistor has lots of gain at 1.1 MHz.Infact you could swap c127 and c129 .Also swap R217 and R 218 .

Answer (score 0):

Use power amplifer transistor to get desired output. But remember that circuit of this type have an issue of stability.